# AND condition and strict equality in loc

Tags: pandas, dataframe, lines-of-code

I need to match the payment of invoices in the DocN column of df1 with the data in the TXT column in df2. Print the document (DocN) + the amount (DocSum) and the details of the corresponding payment (DocP, Date) in accordance with the matching article in both datasets

```
import numpy as np
import re
data1 = {
"DocN": ['140111038-001', '7314560', '169233301-001','ЕКТ01886853','ЕКТ02126350','30262-19',
'27283-19','746'],
"DocSum": ['358,80', '1487,45', '7458,78','2478,12','9624,95','3247,32',
'3224,25','32587,22'],
"DocArt1" : ['85647', '85475', '21457', '12746', '25472', '58123', '74185', '82274']
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {
"TXT": ['payment by document 30262-19, 30317-19, 30329-19, 31270-19, 32038-19, 26713-19,26715-19, ЕКТ01886853 ',
'payment by document 26721-19, 26748-19, 29835-19, 31112-19, 26746-19, 30041-19, 23150-19, ',
'payment by document 23525-19, 25050-19, 26244-19, 27997-19, 28032-19,30278-19, ЕКТ01886853',
'payment by document 29227-19, 29713-19, 27283-19, 32003-19, 29235-19, 29888-19, 7314560',
'payment by document 175634096-001, 175634109-001, 175623281-001,175638863-001, 140111038-001, 7314560'],
"DocP": [112, 113, 114, 115, 116],
"Date": ["25.01.2022", "26.01.2022", "27.01.2022", "28.01.2022", "29.01.2022"],
"DocArt2" : ['12746','74585','25489','85475','85875']
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

print(df1)
print(df2)
```

i'm trying to apply:

`df1.join(df1.DocN.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(df2.loc[df2['TXT'].str.contains(fr'\b{x}\b')& (df1['DocArt1'] == df2['DocArt2']),['DocP','Date']].to_dict('list'))))`

i'm expecting:

| index | DocN | DocSum | DocArt1 | DocP | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 140111038-001 | 358,80 | 85647 | 116 | 29.01.2022 |
| 1 | 7314560 | 1487,45 | 85475 | 115 | 28.01.2022 |
| 2 | 169233301-001 | 7458,78 | 21457 |  |  |
| 3 | ЕКТ01886853 | 2478,12 | 12746 | 112 | 25.01.2022 |
| 4 | ЕКТ02126350 | 9624,95 | 25472 |  |  |
| 5 | 30262-19 | 3247,32 | 58123 | 112 | 25.01.2022 |
| 6 | 27283-19 | 3224,25 | 74185 | 115 | 28.01.2022 |
| 7 | 746 | 32587,22 | 82274 |  |  |

Answer (score 1):

First solution is with [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) and [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), if need match by `DocArt` and `DocN` both columns:

```
pat = r"\b({})\b".format("|".join(re.escape(x) for x in df1.DocN))

need = ['DocArt2','DocN','DocP','Date']
df22 = df2.assign(DocN= df2['TXT'].str.findall(pat)).explode('DocN')[need]
#alternative solution
#df22 = df2.join(df2['TXT'].str.extractall(pat)[0].droplevel(1).rename('DocN'))[need]
print (df22)
  DocArt2           DocN  DocP        Date
0   12746       30262-19   112  25.01.2022
0   12746    ЕКТ01886853   112  25.01.2022
1   74585            NaN   113  26.01.2022
2   25489    ЕКТ01886853   114  27.01.2022
3   85475       27283-19   115  28.01.2022
3   85475        7314560   115  28.01.2022
4   85875  140111038-001   116  29.01.2022
4   85875        7314560   116  29.01.2022

df = df1.merge(df22, left_on=['DocArt1','DocN'], right_on=['DocArt2','DocN'], how='left')
print (df)

            DocN    DocSum DocArt1 DocArt2   DocP        Date
0  140111038-001    358,80   85647     NaN    NaN         NaN
1        7314560   1487,45   85475   85475  115.0  28.01.2022
2  169233301-001   7458,78   21457     NaN    NaN         NaN
3    ЕКТ01886853   2478,12   12746   12746  112.0  25.01.2022
4    ЕКТ02126350   9624,95   25472     NaN    NaN         NaN
5       30262-19   3247,32   58123     NaN    NaN         NaN
6       27283-19   3224,25   74185     NaN    NaN         NaN
7            746  32587,22   82274     NaN    NaN         NaN
```

If need match only by `DocN` with aggregation by same `DocN`:

```
pat = r"\b({})\b".format("|".join(re.escape(x) for x in df1.DocN))

f = lambda x: ', '.join(x.astype(str))
df22 = (df2.assign(DocN= df2['TXT'].str.findall(pat)).explode('DocN')
           .groupby('DocN')[['DocP','Date']].agg(f))
print (df22)
                   DocP                    Date
DocN                                           
140111038-001       116              29.01.2022
27283-19            115              28.01.2022
30262-19            112              25.01.2022
7314560        115, 116  28.01.2022, 29.01.2022
ЕКТ01886853    112, 114  25.01.2022, 27.01.2022

df = df1.merge(df22, on='DocN', how='left')
print (df)
            DocN    DocSum DocArt1      DocP                    Date
0  140111038-001    358,80   85647       116              29.01.2022
1        7314560   1487,45   85475  115, 116  28.01.2022, 29.01.2022
2  169233301-001   7458,78   21457       NaN                     NaN
3    ЕКТ01886853   2478,12   12746  112, 114  25.01.2022, 27.01.2022
4    ЕКТ02126350   9624,95   25472       NaN                     NaN
5       30262-19   3247,32   58123       112              25.01.2022
6       27283-19   3224,25   74185       115              28.01.2022
7            746  32587,22   82274       NaN                     NaN
```

because else get duplicated new rows:

```
pat = r"\b({})\b".format("|".join(re.escape(x) for x in df1.DocN))

need = ['DocN','DocP','Date']
df22 = df2.assign(DocN= df2['TXT'].str.findall(pat)).explode('DocN')[need]
#alternative solution
#df22 = df2.join(df2['TXT'].str.extractall(pat)[0].droplevel(1).rename('DocN'))[need]
print (df22)
            DocN  DocP        Date
0       30262-19   112  25.01.2022
0    ЕКТ01886853   112  25.01.2022
1            NaN   113  26.01.2022
2    ЕКТ01886853   114  27.01.2022
3       27283-19   115  28.01.2022
3        7314560   115  28.01.2022
4  140111038-001   116  29.01.2022
4        7314560   116  29.01.2022

df = df1.merge(df22, on='DocN', how='left')
print (df)
            DocN    DocSum DocArt1   DocP        Date
0  140111038-001    358,80   85647  116.0  29.01.2022
1        7314560   1487,45   85475  115.0  28.01.2022
2        7314560   1487,45   85475  116.0  29.01.2022
3  169233301-001   7458,78   21457    NaN         NaN
4    ЕКТ01886853   2478,12   12746  112.0  25.01.2022
5    ЕКТ01886853   2478,12   12746  114.0  27.01.2022
6    ЕКТ02126350   9624,95   25472    NaN         NaN
7       30262-19   3247,32   58123  112.0  25.01.2022
8       27283-19   3224,25   74185  115.0  28.01.2022
9            746  32587,22   82274    NaN         NaN
```

Comment: ,thanks for your solution. I have a working algorithm, but it's not perfect. `df1.join(df1.DocN.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(df2.loc[df2['TXT'].str.contains(fr'\b{x}\b'),['DocP','Date']].to_dict('list'))))` it doesn't make selections for the same numbers in DocArt1 and DocArt2. That is, I need to add a dataframe formation condition df1['DocArt1'] == df2['DocArt2']

Comment: in this case `df = df1.merge(df22, left_on=['DocArt1','DocN'], right_on=['DocArt2','DocN'], how='left') print (df)`  i lose data

Comment: @user534280 - Can you explain more what data are lost?

Comment: jezrael, I started to understand your answer a little more and I see that it is perfect. Thank you for your help! By the way, I read your article on [towardsdatascience](https://towardsdatascience.com/left-join-with-pandas-data-frames-in-python-c29c85089ba4) thanks for what you are doing, subscribed))